# How to have a checkbox fire an ajax call when checked or unchecked in Rails3?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

In my Rails3 application, I have a group of check boxes for a list of tasks. I'd like to fire off an ajax call back to the server whenever one of the check boxes are checked or unchecked.

This code is part of a much larger form:

```
<% @provider.tasks_assigned.each do |task_assigned| %>
  <%= form_for :task_assigned, :url => { :controller => "tasks_assigned", 
    :action => 'update' }, :remote => true do |t|%>
    <%= t.hidden_field :id, :value => task_assigned.id %>
    <%= t.check_box :provider_completed, 
      { :checked => task_assigned.provider_completed, 
      :onclick => "$(this).parent().trigger('submit.rails');" } %>
    <%= t.label :provider_completed, 
      task_assigned.task_desc.gsub(/(\n\r|\r\n|\n)/, '<br>').html_safe, 
      :style => "color: #666666; margin-top: 0px;" %>
    <br />          
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is the generated html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/tasks_assigned/update" data-remote="true"
  method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden"
    value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden"
      value="jECJ4FkV48T5EgCEE0hhPvsbWjG+WGXn59L2knMv7No=" />
  </div> 
  <input id="task_assigned_id" name="task_assigned[id]" type="hidden" value="25" /> 
  <input name="task_assigned[provider_completed]" type="hidden" value="0" />
  <input id="task_assigned_provider_completed" name="task_assigned[provider_completed]"
    onclick="$(this).parent().trigger('submit.rails');" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
  <label for="task_assigned_provider_completed" 
    style="color: #666666; margin-top: 0px;">abc</label> 
  <br />            
</form>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/tasks_assigned/update" data-remote="true"
  method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden"
      value="jECJ4FkV48T5EgCEE0hhPvsbWjG+WGXn59L2knMv7No=" />
  </div> 
  <input id="task_assigned_id" name="task_assigned[id]" type="hidden" value="24" /> 
  <input name="task_assigned[provider_completed]" type="hidden" value="0" />
  <input id="task_assigned_provider_completed" name="task_assigned[provider_completed]"
    onclick="$(this).parent().trigger('submit.rails');" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
  <label for="task_assigned_provider_completed" 
    style="color: #666666; margin-top: 0px;">Provider completed</label> 
  <br />            
</form>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/tasks_assigned/update" data-remote="true"
  method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden"
      value="jECJ4FkV48T5EgCEE0hhPvsbWjG+WGXn59L2knMv7No=" />
  </div> 
  <input id="task_assigned_id" name="task_assigned[id]" type="hidden" value="22" /> 
  <input name="task_assigned[provider_completed]" type="hidden" value="0" />
  <input id="task_assigned_provider_completed" name="task_assigned[provider_completed]"
    onclick="$(this).parent().trigger('submit.rails');" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
  <label for="task_assigned_provider_completed" 
    style="color: #666666; margin-top: 0px;">a<br>b<br>c</label> 
  <br />    
</form>
```

If I add a submit button in the form it works without any problem but this doesn't look very appealing.

The 'onclick="$(this).parent().trigger('submit.rails');"' is my vain attempt to trigger the rails submit code when the check box is checked. The parent (the form) is never found. A javascript error is generated "Object # has no method 'parent'".

I believe I am very close to getting it figured out, but I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Are you sure you're running jquery and not prototype? Also, you should just be able to do .submit() instead of trigger('submit.rails')... I'm doing the same thing on my own site.

Comment: I'm at least trying to do jQuery. I've tryed a simple submit() and it does a regular post of the whole page, not a ajax post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a class to your checkboxes, remove the obtrusive onclick and use jQuery to fire the form submit unobtrusively.

```
<%= t.check_box :provider_completed, 
  { :checked => task_assigned.provider_completed, 
  {:class => 'checkable'} } %>

$('.checkable').live('change', 
function() {
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use the standard .submit() but add .submit();return false; to it you'll have it.