# Display checkbox best_in_place ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, best-in-place

I am using the best_in_place gem in a project, and i am trying to display a checkbox on it's own place, but i cannot do it. I am searching about it, but i cannot find out the answer anywhere. I just  can find people talking about display either "no" or "yes"... Or anything else. But i just want to see the checkbox checked or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am using font-awesome but you can use it also with bootstrap or other images. My solution for displaying checkboxes were simply using the [`raw` method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw) to render a checkbox image (in my case one of the [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/#examples) icons)

```
= best_in_place @project, 
    :active, 
    :type => :checkbox, 
    :collection => {false: raw("<i class='icon-check-empty'></i>"), true: raw("<i class='icon-check'></i>")}
```

And now it looks like the following:

[image: best_in_place with checkboxes]

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to make a hack-around using unicode characters ☐ and ☑

```
<span style='font-size: 1.75em;'>
<%= best_in_place a,
:bool, 
:type => :checkbox,
:collection => ["&#x2610;", "&#x2611;"]%>
</span>
```

The `<span>` wrapper helps with choosing the size in this case. This is a short term solution and a checkbox with an AJAX call would definitely be better I guess...

Comment: @megas, try encapsulating @Sash's collection with raw: `:collection => [raw("&#x2610;"), raw("&#x2611;")]`

Answer (score 1):

I've forked the original `best_in_place` gem and modified it with support for displaying an actual, standard HTML checkbox.  My fork can be found here: https://github.com/jdashton/best_in_place

In case you're unfamiliar with using gems directly from github, the following line in your Gemfile should do the trick:

```
gem 'best_in_place', github: 'jdashton/best_in_place'
```

Comment: I wish this would be merged in to the actual gem :/

Answer (score -1):

It's not supported in the current version. However, it's pretty easy to do. Create a checkbox where you need it, and fire an ajax call to the server with some javascript.

Check out [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082250/how-to-have-a-checkbox-fire-an-ajax-call-when-checked-or-unchecked-in-rails3) answer for an example.